How to space out varying width text in HStack so centre of the text is positioned correctly?
I have created a slider that has 5 "steps". The user can slide between "0" to "Step 1" and "Step 2" etc. Each step is evenly spaced out based on the width of the slider.
Here is how the slider can be seen:
| -------- | -------- |--------| -------- |
Every "|" is a step. I would like to align the text directly underneath each "|" with left and right most text to be aligned .leading and .trailing. The problem is that the text is slightly uneven in length. So some text can be 3 letters, others can be 7-8 letters. If I use the HStack to space out the text it doesn't centre align correctly with the step for the 3 steps in the middle.
What would be the best way to align the text so that the centre of the text is directly underneath the step?
The slider I am using is custom built and on drag it goes from one step to the other. Again the step width is total width / 4.
I also wanted to ask if it is possible to keep the width between the labels the same as well while the text is correctly aligned underneath the steps.?
You can think of the step in the picture below is just where the rounded edge of the rounded rectangle is.


I was suggesting in a comment that you set .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) on every label. Unfortunately, it's not quite as simple as that, because the first and last labels only need half the space of the other labels.
Another complication is that you probably need to add a small amount of horizontal padding when adding the tick marks, otherwise the slider button does not align with the marks at the beginning and the end.
Here are two possible ways to solve:
1. Use .matchedGeometryEffect
If you have found a way to position the tick marks, then .matchedGeometryEffect can be used to match the position of the labels to the position of the tick marks.

The slider values (from 1 to 5) can be used as the ids.
The tick marks are used as the sources, the labels have isSource: false.
Only the position of the tick mark needs to be matched.
The exact alignment of a label with a tick mark can be controlled by adding anchor as parameter.
The first and last labels can use negative padding to compensate for the tick-mark padding, if required.

struct ContentView: View {
    let tickPadding: CGFloat = 12
    @State private var value = 0.0
    @Namespace private var ns

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $value, in: 1...5, step: 1)
            .frame(maxWidth: 300)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
            .background {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { i in
                        Color.pink
                            .frame(width: 2)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: i, in: ns, anchor: .bottom)
                        if i < 5 {
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, tickPadding)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .background {
                ZStack {
                    Text("First")
                        .padding(.leading, -tickPadding)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: ns, properties: .position, anchor: .topLeading, isSource: false)
                    Text("Second")
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 2, in: ns, properties: .position, anchor: .top, isSource: false)
                    Text("Third")
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 3, in: ns, properties: .position, anchor: .top, isSource: false)
                    Text("Fourth")
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 4, in: ns, properties: .position, anchor: .top, isSource: false)
                    Text("Last")
                        .padding(.trailing, -tickPadding)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 5, in: ns, properties: .position, anchor: .topTrailing, isSource: false)
                }
                .font(.subheadline)
            }
    }
}

2. Use a GeometryReader
Alternatively, a GeometryReader can be used to measure the available width. Then you can distribute the labels over this width, allowing for the horizontal padding in any way you prefer.
struct ContentView: View {
    let tickPadding: CGFloat = 12
    @State private var value = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $value, in: 1...5, step: 1)
            .frame(maxWidth: 300)
            .background {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 2)
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 2)
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 2)
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 2)
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 2)
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.pink)
                .padding(.horizontal, tickPadding)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            .background {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    let cellWidth = (proxy.size.width - (tickPadding * 2)) / 4
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("First").frame(width: (cellWidth / 2) + tickPadding, alignment: .leading)
                        Text("Second").frame(width: cellWidth)
                        Text("Third").frame(width: cellWidth)
                        Text("Fourth").frame(width: cellWidth)
                        Text("Last").frame(width: (cellWidth / 2) + tickPadding, alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                }
            }
    }
}

The result looks the same in both cases:


EDIT Based on the update to your post, I understand that in fact there will be no tick marks and you simply want to spread the labels evenly.
To keep the gaps between the labels the same, just show the labels in an HStack with a Spacer between each of them:
Slider(value: $value, in: 1...5, step: 1)
    .frame(maxWidth: 300)
    .padding(.bottom, 30)
    .background(alignment: .bottom) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("None")
            Spacer()
            Text("Low")
            Spacer()
            Text("Standard")
            Spacer()
            Text("High")
            Spacer()
            Text("Extreme")
        }
        .font(.subheadline)
    }


However, you will notice from the position of the slider button in this screenshot that the labels are not positioned exactly below the slider stops.
The slider stops are always evenly spaced, so this means:

either, the labels can be shown immediately below the stops (as per the solutions shown earlier in this answer), in which case the gaps between the labels will not be even;
or, the labels are not immediately below the stops, but the gaps between them can be even, as per the update here.

Unfortunately, you can't have even label spacing and labels below the stops. If you want to have slider stops that are unevenly spaced, you probably need to create a custom slider.

Answer updated again to reflect the updated post.


You can use the overlay with the fixedSize text like this:
Circle()
  .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
    Text(title)
      .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { $0[.top] } //  Push it directly the mark underneath
      .fixedSize() //  Resist the compression
  }

You can add horizontal .padding to the HStack equal to half the size of the nub if needed.

A demo code
struct MarkView: View {
    var title: String

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                Text(title)
                    .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { $0[.top] } //  Push it directly underneath
                    .fixedSize() //  Resist the compression
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var progress = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Capsule().foregroundStyle(.indigo) // Consider this a a placeholder of the slider

            HStack {
                MarkView(title: "AAAAAA")
                Spacer()
                MarkView(title: "A")
                Spacer()
                MarkView(title: "AA")
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 20)
    }
}


How are we supposed to space out the dots in the HStack?  Are you using simple spacer here?

Yes, simple spacers between these circles. If you post the minimum code, I can integrate this method and update the answer

Thanks. I have edited the answer. The slider isn't the default one but is a custom one. But the idea is same. The custom slider rounded edge can be treated as the step. And it offsets = width of slider / 4  in X-direction. Hope the image will help

I've used a capsule as a place holder for your custom slider. Hope it helps
